# Rotating animation wobbles

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm trying to create a simple *"AJAX loader*" type animation, just a circle that rotates around it's center. My problem is that the rotation isn't smooth, it wobbles slightly back and forth.

Demo SWF: http://swfup.com/view/1mn0

Code for the swf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="160" height="160" 

               backgroundColor="0xCCCCCC"
               initialize="loadingAnim.play()">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Rotate angleFrom="0" angleTo="360" autoCenterTransform="true" id="loadingAnim" target="{loader}" 
                  repeatCount="0" duration="2000" easer="{null}" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Image id="loader" source="@Embed('loader.png')" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />

</s:Application>
```

I've made sure that the image is an exact circle, if you want to check for yourself then here is the image file:

[image: Loading Image]

Answer (score 0):

The center of the image (73, 73) doesn't match up to the visual center of the graphic.
Here's your graphic with the center marked:
[image: loader with center marked]

So, it's spinning off-center (visually) which causes it wobble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check that in the morning. But actually it's not the lines that appear to wobble, it's the outside edge.

Comment: I have corrected the lines on the image, these are dead center now. I've also updated the demo SWF url, but it still shows the circle wobble.